# Teradata SQL - Qualify max / row / rank

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Below is the sample data I have

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3NEv.png)

I am trying to get either of two outputs whichever is possible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjuHz.png)

or

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JljEX.png)

I have tried multiple different qualify statements in the where clause but I am unable to crack it. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I have tried multiple different qualify statements in the where clause but I am unable to crack it. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Not sure if I am not using group by is causing it or should I be creating case statements to simplify before using qualify?

Comment: You need to explain your logic. And you better show the data inline instead of image links

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, Sorry for any confusion. In the first image I am trying to get the last column "Rank" by sequ and then section as you can see the last column (output needed) in the first image... Thanks

Comment: Could you please post text instead of images.